# What happens if you silence C'Thun?

Tags: hearthstone

The developers have stated many times that the buff to C'Thun works more like an aura than an actual buff so I was wondering this: can C'Thun be silenced if I somehow survive the initial onslaught? What happens then? Does the silence remove the whole buff from C'Thun (*wherever it is*) or does it just fizzle?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can silence an in-play C'thun to revert it to a 6/6.

However, if a silenced C'thun later gets sent back to its owner's hand or deck, it will regain its buffed stats.

The aura still applies to cards like Klaxxi Amberweaver, which check for C'thun having 10+ Attack, as reported [here](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/20743654326).

Comment: Just found out that the aura applies even if C'thun is not in your deck. The popup of the buff won't show up, but the condition still applies for cards like Klaxxi Amberweaver or Vek'lor

Comment: During the Top Two tavern brawl I verified that if you have multiple C'thun, only one popup appears, and the buffs affect all copies in your hand or deck.  While this doesn't directly answer the question, it adds support to the aura being something that is tracked separately from the actual card.